# org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to run a simple user login with Spring MVC 3 and weird things are happening.

My environment:

- Eclipse Helios 3.6
- GlassFish 3
- Java 6

**Libraries: WEB-INF/lib**

```
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
log4j-1.2.14.jar
servlet-2.3.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar
spring-asm-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
standard.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
```

Here is the full stack of the log server

```
    WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at javax.persistence.Persistence$PersistenceUtilImpl.isLoaded(Persistence.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.isReachable(SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:764)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForRedefinedDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:119)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:692)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doBind(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:806)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:170)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:421)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:774)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:732)

WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at javax.persistence.Persistence$PersistenceUtilImpl.isLoaded(Persistence.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.isReachable(SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:764)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForRedefinedDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:119)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:692)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doBind(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:806)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:170)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:421)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:409)
    at
```

**Dispatcher-Servlet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Enable annotation driven controllers, validation etc... -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="net.extCoder.controllers" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />
</bean>

<!-- Configure the multipart resolver -->
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">      
</bean>

</beans>
```

I read somewhere that it could be a library dependency issue, but after playing around with different versions and even the most recent of all, I have the same issue.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the beast !!!! There was an old **"toplink-essentials.jar"** hanging out in my glassfish/lib directory. I dropped it there sometimes back when I was playing around with one of my applications. So I removed the that jar and it works like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by presence of incomplete or incompatible JPA implementation in the classpath, perhaps as a part of GlassFish. I'm not sure how to solve it. See also [HV-425](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HV-425) and related issues.

Comment: the issue explained in the link looks quite similar. Thanks for the link.